# Android Clickable Custom View before app icon on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have a custom view before app icon on the action bar. That custom view is actually menu button as you see in facebook. I also want the UP button i.e. Home button too. So can we either place an icon to the left of the app icon or otherwise show some other image as app icon but that image should not be seen in the app drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got some workaround for this. I applied custom view to my action bar and removed app icon. And had an imageview with app icon on my custom view. For those who are interested, this is how my custom view on action bar xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:paddingLeft="14dip"
    android:paddingRight="14dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_off" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_separator"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/separator1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_separator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_app_icon" />       

</RelativeLayout>
```